# How do I support jasmine and es6 syntax in Visual studio Code?

Tags: jasmine, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

Question where can I find and how do I add support for jasmine and es6 syntax in Visual studio code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the only Q&A item in the section [Common Questions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages#_common-questions) support for user defined languages is not possible at the moment. So if the language is not supported out of the box, then it's not supported.

But support for it may be [near](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752666-pluggable-intellisense-for-user-languages), and support for ES6 may be [even nearer](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752489-es6-es2015-support).